# Showing that a certain conformal map is sequentially proper

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

I am trying to find another way of showing that there is no conformal map from $\mathbb{C}\setminus 0 \to \mathbb{D}$.  The easy way is by using the boundedness of the map, followed by the Riemann removable singularity theorem, and the maximum principle.

I want to show that any conformal map $\mathbb{C} \setminus 0 \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{D}$ is a covering projection.  This would be true if I could show that $f$ is a necessarily a proper map.

Hence I need to show that if $\{x_n\}$ escapes to infinity in $\mathbb C \setminus 0$, then $f(x_n)$ escapes to infinity.  I would be happy with a proof that if  $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$ then $f(x_n)$ escapes to infinity.

This clearly requires me to use that $f$ is holomorphic - otherwise I could take the contraction map(which is also a local diffeo) $\mathbb{C} \setminus 0  \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}  \to B_{1/4}(1/2) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{D}$.

Comment: I do not think this is any easier than the original problem. Note that there are locally univalent surjective holomorphic maps ${\mathbb C}\to {\mathbb C}$ which are not proper.